# Find PI to the Nth Digit - in python - this is intended to get an simple solution

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, wxpython

Enter a number and have the program generate PI up to that many decimal places. Keep a limit to how far the program will go.

i've tried the below code snippet

But is there any way to write a simple code

```
from numpy import *

n = int(input('how many digits after decimal you want to limit'))

print(n)


print('{:.2f}'.format(pi))
```

## print('{:.nf}'.format(pi)) here i want to use the digits after decimals in PI as requested by the user

'' Here i have tried using a n in the place of two 
                               but it throws an error ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `print('{pi:0.{precision}f}'.format(pi=pi,precision=3))`

that said this is not "calculating" pi to the nth digit... so depending on what `pi` is this might not work for large precision values...

Comment: Thanks Joran Beasley!! the  solution you provided is simple and Really Fantastic

Comment: not work for an N greater than 50 `3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500000000000000000`

Comment: hence my comment about it not really calculating pi